# Export to excel return "You do not have permission to view the entire list because it is larger than the list view threshold enforced by the admin""

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, list-view-threshold, large-lists

We have a list view which contain less than 400 items, the list it self contain 33,000 items. Now we have a list view which have this filtering and sorting based on indexed columns (all the fields Short code + Design Period + FY are indexed):-

[image: User's image]

and when we try to export the list view using Excel >> we got this error:-

[image: User's image]

although the list view only contain less than 400 items and we can export it to csv. so why we can not export a list view which return less than 400 items and has all its filtering using indexed columns to excel ??

Thanks